# Cannot install "Microsoft.AspNet.Razor 3.2.3" at the nuget package manager visual studio 2015

Tags: c#, razor, xamarin, xamarin.android, nuget-package

Cannot install "Microsoft.AspNet.Razor 3.2.3" at the nuget package manager visual studio 2015.

> Install-Package : Could not install package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Razor 3.2.3'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'MonoAndroid,Version=v5.0', but the package does not contain any assembly  references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

Answer (score 2):

The Microsoft.AspNet.Razor 3.2.3 NuGet package only contains an assembly for .NET 4.5 so you cannot use it in a MonoAndroid project.

A .NET 4.5 assembly may use an API that is not supported by MonoAndroid. NuGet considers them to be incompatible.

Answer (score 1):

The Microsoft.AspNet.Razor NuGet package can be installed into a project. It may fail if you do not have the Xamarin Portable Class Library (PCL) profiles or  or the Mono frameworks installed.

see here : http://lastexitcode.com/blog/2014/11/16/InstallingPortableClassLibrariesForXamarinStudio/